# get_category display only 1

Tags: php, categories

I found this code that works perfectly what I'm working on but needs a minor changes. What I need is to just display the sub categories of the parent.

How do I alter the `get_categories()` to only get the specific categories I need? because doing this will display all available categories.

```
function ba_SearchFilter($query) {
    if (!$query->is_search) {
        return $query;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['cat'])){
        $query->set('category__and', $_POST['cat']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['tags'])){
        $query->set('tag__and', $_POST['tags']);
    }
    return $query;
}
//hook filters to search
add_filter('pre_get_posts','ba_SearchFilter');

function ba_search_with_filters(){
    $out = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="'. home_url( '/' ).'">
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" /><br />';
            $categories=  get_categories(); 
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $option = '';
                $option .= '<input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" id="cat[]" value="'.$category->term_id.'"> ';
                $option .= $category->cat_name .'<br />';
                $out.= $option;
            }
            $tags=  get_categories(); 
            foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                $option = '';
                $option .= '<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" id="tags[]" value="'.$tag->term_id.'"> ';
                $option .= $tag->cat_name .'<br />';
                $out.= $option;
            }
    $out .='<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
        </div>
        </form>';
    return $out;
}

add_shortcode('search_with_filter','ba_search_with_filters');
```

Answer (score 0):

Added an argument for the `$categories`
Input the ID of the parent to display all the subcategories.

```
function ba_SearchFilter($query) {
    if (!$query->is_search) {
        return $query;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['cat'])){
        $query->set('category__and', $_POST['cat']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['tags'])){
        $query->set('tag__and', $_POST['tags']);
    }
    return $query;
}
//hook filters to search
add_filter('pre_get_posts','ba_SearchFilter');

function ba_search_with_filters(){
    $out = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="'. home_url( '/' ).'">
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" /><br />';
        $args = array ( 'child_of' => 1 );
            $categories=  get_categories( $args ); 
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $option = '';
                $option .= '<input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" id="cat[]" value="'.$category->term_id.'"> ';
                $option .= $category->cat_name .'<br />';
                $out.= $option;
            }
    $out .='<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
        </div>
        </form>';
    return $out;
}

add_shortcode('search_with_filter','ba_search_with_filters');
```

Comment: you don't need to post an answer with modified code. Just update your original question and delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Get the current category you're in based on the `$_POST`. Then get all child categories.

```
$args = array();

if ( isset( $_POST['cat'] ) ) {
  $args = array( 'child_of' => (int) $_POST['cat'] );
}

$categories = get_categories( $args );
```

Comment: Please explain how this code solves the question

Answer (score 0):

Replace below two line code:

`$categories=  get_categories();` to `$categories=  get_categories(array('hide_empty' => 0 ));`

and

`$tags=  get_categories();`  to `$tags=  get_categories(array('hide_empty' => 0 ));`

I add `array('hide_empty' => 0 )` parameter to skip empty list. Hope this help you well!